# AsyncTask, progress and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a activity that show a progress-bar fragment, loads-data and then shows it in a new fragment, after hiding the progress-bar fragment.

I ran into the infamous onPostExecute() / configuration-change problem, and after reading numerous posts about possible solutions, i figured non of them deals with switching fragments in onPostExecute() - which can also be potentially hazardous since it might throw IllegalStateException while trying tho commit a fragment transaction after the activity has saved it's state.

That's the piece of relevant code:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements {

    class LoadListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MyListItem> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            showProgressBar();
        }

        @Override
        protected Response doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //
            // ... web call
            //
            return new List<MyListItem>;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(List<MyListItem> result) {
            if (result != null) {
                hideProgressBar();
                showList(result);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(...);
        new LoadListTask().execute(session);
    }

    public void showProgressBar() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.placeholder,
                mProgressBarFragment).commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    }

    private void hideProgressBar() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.remove(mProgressBarFragment)
                .commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    }

    private void showList(List<ListItem> list) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();

        Fragment frg = FacebookFriendPickerFragment
                .newInstance(friendsArrObj);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.friendPickerPlaceholder, frg)
                .commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

I'm starting to think that having a fragment that merely show progress complicates things, but i really do want to stick to fragments - so is there any way to "synchronize" the fragment-transaction so it would happen in a reasonable phase of the activity life-cycle, and avoid the AsyncTask/config-change issue?

Answer (score 1):

you need to put this code to your fragment:

```
// Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
setRetainInstance(true);
```

more about handling configuration changes with fragments you can read in this tutorial:

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Hope, I help you.

Comment: Thanks, i've read this post as well, and tried setRetainInstance(true) when the problem first appeared, but as expected it only controls the fragment itself - while my problem is that the activity needs to switch fragments in the onPostExecute(), and not the fragment being destroyed.

Comment: you wrote this - "configuration-change problem...".. I hoped that if you read this post you find some solution... sorry but I haven't any other idea.